# Solving linear system and find impulse response

Tags: frequency, frequency-response, impulse-response, linear-systems

I have this linear system that is defined by the differential equation 
    $$
    y''(t) + 4y'(t) + 5y(t) = 2x(t) + 3x'(t)
    $$
with x(t) the input and y(t) the output. I'm asked to find two things: The output when x(t) = cos(t), and the impulse response

This is what I did: First, I found the frequency response,H(f)
    $$
    H(f) = \frac{2 + 6\pi fj}{8\pi fj -4\pi^2 f^2+5}
    $$

Second, I found the Fourier Transform of cos(t) which equals to: 
    $$
    X(f) = \frac{1}{2}\delta (f-\frac{1}{2\pi }) + \frac{1}{2}\delta (f+\frac{1}{2\pi })
    $$

Now, the output basically would be
    $$
    Y(f) = H(f)\ X(f)
    $$
Is it possible to simplify the answer of Y(f)?

For the second part of the question, I found the impulse response using Laplace Transform
    $$
    h(t) = [\frac{-17}{6} e^{5t} - \frac{1}{6} e^{-t}]u(t)
    $$

What do you think about my answer? Is it possible to use Z-transform to find h(t)?

Comment: The output is **not** $Y(f) = H(f)*X(f)$ if by $*$ you mean _convolution._  Do not mix up standard notation in system theory with the conventions of programming languages.

Comment: Hint: $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty G(f)\delta(f-f_0)e^{-j2\pi f t}\, \mathrm df = G(f_0)e^{-j 2\pi f_0 t}$ provided that $G(f)$ is continuous at $f = f_0$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate No. Sorry, I didn't mean convolution. Just a multiplication. :)

Comment: Then, please **edit** your question to express $Y(f)$ properly, and then use the hint I provided in my second comment to obtain the output.  Note that the output is $y(t)$, not $Y(f)$ as you claim it is.

Comment: @Sultan: The $z$-transform is used for discrete-time systems. It would not be appropriate to use here.

Comment: @JasonR got it ;)

Comment: @DilipSarwate Are you sure about the hint? Isn't G(f0)exp(j*2*pi*f0*t)?. Note that the exp with a positive sign.

Comment: The statement is correct as I have written it but to apply it to _your_ problem, you will need to change the sign of $t$ so that you get the inverse Fourier transform formula.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Well, to do the inverse Fourier transform, the sign of **t** you have written before the equal sign has to be positive.

Comment: Since $t$ is just a **constant** as far as the integration is concerned, the integral that I wrote gives you $\mathcal F^{-1}[G(f)\delta(f-f_0)](-t)$. The hint can **still** be used but since you prefer to natter instead, $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty G(f)\delta(f-f_0)e^{j2\pi f t}\, \mathrm df = G(f_0)e^{j2\pi f_0t}$$ **and** $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty G(f)\delta(f+f_0)e^{j2\pi f t}\, \mathrm df = G(-f_0)e^{-j2\pi f_0t}.$$  Any other $i$'s you want dotted or $t$'s you want crossed?

Comment: @DilipSarwate I prefer clear answer :)